# Stack using binaries of other package

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have two projects in my user directory `~`, the project `A` and `B`.
I run `stack init` and later `stack build` on the project `A`. Then, I have
the binaries of the `A` package in a folder `~/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-6.0/7.10.3/bin`. The issue is `B` needs this version of the binaries from `A` package, and then try the same build with `stack` on the `B` project directory. I tried on `~/B` run the following command without success.

`stack build ~/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-6.0/7.10.3/bin`

How can I do that? What if I create a third package `C`, and need something similar?

Excerpts:

The `A.cabal` content.

```
name: A
version: 1.1
```

And the `B.cabal`.

```
name: B
version: 1.0
build-depends: A>= 1.1
```

Then,

```
$ stack init
Looking for .cabal or package.yaml files to use to init the project.
Using cabal packages:
- B.cabal

Selecting the best among 8 snapshots...

* Partially matches lts-6.0
    A version 1.0 found
        - A requires ==1.1
```

This may be resolved by:
    - Using '--omit-packages to exclude mismatching package(s).
    - Using '--resolver' to specify a matching snapshot/resolver

But I actually have the version 1.1 of `A` build.

Comment: Can you post your .cabal files from both projects? Try to come up with the smallest example which demonstrates the problem. I would like to see in the .cabal file how project B refers to stuff from project A.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include the project A's `bin` directory - that was a red herring.

Organize your files like this:

```
.
├── stack.yaml
├── project-A
│   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   ├── Setup.hs
│   ├── project-A.cabal
│   └── src
│       └── ...
│
└── project-B
    ├── Setup.hs
    ├── project-B.cabal
    └── src
        └── ...
```

Your top-level stack.yaml file will look like:

```
resolver: lts-5.13
packages:
- project-A/
- project-B/
```

Then in the top-level directory run `stack build`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at answering your question...

How about putting

```
~/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-6.0/7.10.3/bin
```

in your `PATH`? If the other project really needs *binaries* (i.e. programs) built by another project, this would be the way to do it.

Or, copy the built programs to some directory in your current `PATH` - i.e. /usr/local/bin or ~/bin.

If this doesn't answer your question, please post the cabal files for both projects.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer after digging into the [FAQ](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/faq.md) of `stack`. Create a file `stack.yaml` into `B` folder. At first the content could be:

```
resolver: lts-6.0
packages:
- '.'
- '/home/jonaprieto/A'

extra-deps: []
```

Then, it runs:

`$ stack build`